# How could I cancel task with different threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, async-await, task

I'm writing an own TelegramBot. In that Bot there is a function subscribe/unsubscribe. When user starts "Subscribtion" TelegramBot should send a message "1111" each three seconds. But after unsubscription message keep sending. Could someone help me with that issue?

Method for start subscription:

```
private async Task OnStartSubscribeAsync(string userName, long userId,
    ITelegramBotClient _client, long chatId)
{
    var user = new UserDTO
    {
        UserId = userId.ToString(),
        UserName = userName
    };
    await _userService.StartSubscribeAsync(user);
    await _client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "You subscribed successfully ");

    try
    {
        await CheckTick(_client, chatId);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e)
    {
        await _client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "STOPPED");
    }
    finally
    {
        tokenSource.Dispose();
    }

    var articles = await ReturnNewArticles();
    foreach (var item in articles)
    {
        var linkButton = KeyboardGoOver("Перейти", (EncodeUrl(item.Href)));
        await _client.SendPhotoAsync(chatId: chatId, photo: item.Image,
            caption: $"*{item.Title}*",
            parseMode: Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode.Markdown,
            replyMarkup: linkButton);
    }
}
```

Method for sending message with delay:

```
private Task CheckTick(ITelegramBotClient _client, long chatId)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            await _client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "1111");
            if (tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }

    }, tokenSource.Token);
}
```

Method for unsubscribe:

```
private async Task OnStopSubscibeAsync(string userName, long userId,
    ITelegramBotClient _client, long chatId)
{
    var user = new UserDTO()
    {
        UserId = userId.ToString(),
        UserName = userName
    };
    await _userService.StopSubscribeAsync(user);
    tokenSource.Cancel();

    await _client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "You unsubscribed successfully");

}
```

Definition of tokenSource:
`private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new();`

I think there are some issues with `CancelationToken` with threads. When I tried to debug, I didn't hit to block "catch".

Comment: So the `tokenSource` field is assigned to a new `CancellationTokenSource` instance only once, and it's never reassigned, even after its cancellation?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, you are right. Does it incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on tokenSource.Cancel() in OnStopSubscibeAsync and on tokenSource.Dispose() in OnStartSubscribeAsync? Which one is hit first?

Comment: @Steeeve, yes I tried, but it called just tokenSouce.Stop(). After that messeages keep sending and it doesn't call a sourceTorken.Dispose(). Maybe I have a two different toukenSource for two threads, for example?

Comment: You should include all the code that touches `tokenSource`. In general it is no problem passing the CancellationTokenSource.Token to many tasks, so the problem has to do with how you are creating/canceling/disposing the source.

Comment: The problem you describe could be a result of race conditions while replacing `CancellationTokenSource` instances. If your program uses just a single `CancellationTokenSource` instance for its whole lifetime, my suggestion will be to make clear your intentions by declaring the `tokenSource` field as `readonly`, so that we can safely dismiss this possibility.

Comment: Probably you will need one CTS per client as you can have more than one subscribed client, so you can't have a single one for all clients. So it should reside somewhere in the implementation of `ITelegramBotClient`.

Comment: I made a field as a readonly, but it doesn't help. ITelegramBotClient is a just library for working with Telegram. Should I create a tokenSource in the OnStartSubscribe method?

Comment: You'll have to associate one CTS with a client, whatever way. Otherwise you don't know which one of them to cancel. I don't know if ITelegramBotClient has a unique identifier, you could use it in a Dictionary<ClientId, CancellationTokenSource> for example.

Comment: thanks, but where should I create a CTS? Should it be in the OnStartSubscribe method?

Comment: How/where are you calling the `OnStopSubscibeAsync` method? Also could replace this: `await Task.Delay(3000)` with this: `await Task.Delay(3000, tokenSource.Token)`, to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @Ilya Yes, OnStartSubscribe would be the right place.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I'm not an expirence in awsync/await. What difference between these calls?

Comment: Ilya configuring the `Task.Delay` with a token means that when the token is canceled, the `Task.Delay` task will also get canceled immediately.

Comment: @Steeeve I don't know how it's working. But Dictionary in method OnStopReceving is always null. Could you help me?

Comment: As a side note, checking `token.IsCancellationRequested` before `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is redundant. The `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` does this check internally ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs.html#d2864d73804288fc)).

Comment: Post the code how you tried to solve it, we can't only gues where the problem resides.

Comment: I edited question and added a new functionality. Please, check)

Comment: Ilya could you format the code properly, and also split long lines of code by adding line-breaks so that the code is visible without horizontal scrolling?

Comment: And even more important, add the classes containing the methods and fields. It is unclear how the methods relate to each other and where they get called.

Comment: Actually no, we shouldn't try to debug a continuously changing piece of code. If you don't mind, I am rolling back the question to the revision 3.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I took that part of code from MSDN. Sorry< I don't understand how I could resolve that issue

Comment: Ilya you could include in the question the link of the MSDN document, where the code is originated from.